# Is php readfile() RCE possible in this case?

Tags: php

I am very sorry if this is a duplicate, but i cant seem to find examples if there is a part of string in front on readfile(), this is the code a friend of mine created, and I feel like some sort of Remote Code Execution is possible, but php:// as parameter wont work because downloads/ is added in front, I already found that i am able to show every file readable by php with the parameter ../something.

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['f'];
$file = 'downloads/' . $filename;

if ( !file_exists($file) )
{
    echo $file;
    exit('404 - File not found');
}

readfile($file);
```

Comment: I can't think of an RCE, but that allows anyone to read any file that the user executing that code can read. Not only in the download folder, "downloads/../" equals the parent folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how you could do RCE in this case. However, being able to read arbitrary files is still a pretty serious vulnerability. Additionally, outputting user-supplied input without sanitizing (echo $file) could lead you open to XSS attacks.

In this case I would still restrict special characters from the 'f' parameter (e.g.: ".", "/" and "\"), or better yet, do whitelist validation and define the allowed format for that parameter. For additional information check out:

https://www.exploit-db.com/papers/12871/

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet#Whitelisting_vs_blacklisting